# Django ORM: filter by hour range

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I'm trying to implement a filter for hour range, it should returns records with a date between hourA and hourB (ie: "give me the records saved between 16pm and 18pm").
My attempts:

1) Using new 1.6 `__hour` filter and `__in` or `__range`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__hour__in=(16, 17, 18))
MyModel.objects.filter(date__hour__range=(16, 18))
```

The code above generates exceptions

2) Using Q objects:

```
hList = [Q(date__hour=h) for h in (16, 17, 18)]
MyModel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, hList))
```

This version works, but is very inefficient, since for each hour in the range it repeats the extract() call by generating something like:

```
   where 
   extract(hour from date) = 16 or 
   extract(hour from date) = 17 or 
   extract(hour from date) = 18
```

when instead the right raw SQL should be:

```
where extract(hour from date) in (16, 17, 18)
```

…how can I filter by hour range in an effective manner, without relying on raw sql?

Comment: how about using `__gte` and `__lte` instead of `__in` ?

Comment: Do you mean date__hour__gte and date__hour__lte? If so, as far I saw it's not possible to chain filters in that way :(

Comment: @daveoncode Did you ever figure it out? I have the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately no :( ...the only way is to use raw SQL at the moment (if you care about optimization)... I hope future versions of Django will implement that kind of filter, or a simple way to extend the existent ones :P

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue in this way:

```
    all_points = MyModel.objects.all()
    all_points.extra(where=['extract(hour from MyDateField) in (16, 17, 18)'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Django 1.9+ you can chain hour lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/#models), so the examples from the question will work:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__hour__in=(16, 17, 18))
MyModel.objects.filter(date__hour__range=(16, 18))
```