# How to filter by hour in Django 1.6+

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter `Performance` by `start_time` hour using Django 1.6. In the console I see :

```
>>> Performance.objects.first().start_time
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 6, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> Performance.objects.first().start_time.hour
11
```

But then, from the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#hour:

```
>>> Performance.objects.filter(start_time__hour=11)
[]
```

How can I filter by hour? Very similar to this (currently unanswered) question: [Django ORM: filter by hour range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958391/django-orm-filter-by-hour-range).

From `models.py`:

```
class Performance(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
...
```

Comment: "When USE_TZ is True, values are converted to the current time zone before filtering." this might be the reason??

Comment: Unfortunately not @almalki , I get the same result for any hour 0-23.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested this in my own project and it works fine. It looks to me like you're doing everything right. As @almalki noted, the attribute access will give the stored UTC time while the query will use the local time, so the result above is normal if you're using `USE_TZ` and aren't running in UTC locally. But something's off if you tried every hour and didn't get any results...

Comment: I created some test cases and all are working fine. You can see generated SQL statements and run it in your DB

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. It turns out I had to load timezone tables in mysql. The hour filter uses a `CONVERT_TZ` statement, which returns `NULL` without the timezone tables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to load timezone tables in MYSQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

There's a small note in the docs, under https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes

Comment: @almalki Planning on it, but SO imposes a two day wait for accepting your own answer. Wouldn't want to do anything rash :)